# Why I'm getting wrong notification?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, reputation, notifications

Today I got a new notification "Congrats, you've gained the privilege – comment everywhere learn more".

[image: Screenshot of the notification]

I tried to comment on a post, but I was not able to comment on any post. After some investigation I got to know that 50 Reputation points on Ask Ubuntu is required to gain 'comment everywhere' privilege. Why am I getting this notification even though my current reputation on Ask Ubuntu is 36?

Comment: There, now you can :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would hesitate a guess that you were temporarily awarded an accept vote and that knocked you up to 51 rep. I believe the notifications are a simple queue so that's when the notification was pushed to your queue.

When the accepted status was withdrawn, you fell back to 36 rep.

Either that or somebody voted for two answers, or four questions (or a combination of those) and retracted their votes, but it's far less likely than somebody accidentally clicking a tick.

Comment: I accidentally click 'a tick' all the time :P  Its especially bad when its a downvote.

Comment: @Oli This seems to be the valid point. Today i also noticed that notification queue is a not updated as soon as event occurs. Thanks. Accepting your answer.